# How to list a string of Months in chronological order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a `BudgetHistory` class and in that class I have `Title` property declared as `public string Title`. The title is set to the month and year of the `BudgetHistory` item so if you want to look at the history of the February budget for the year 2017 then the name of that is February 2017. I am trying to order the string so that the months appear in chronological order when they are iterated over. So when I do my `foreach` loop over my `BudgetHistory` model the list should appear as Jan., Feb., March, etc. How would I go about doing this?

This is what my `foreach` loop looks like right now:

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">

    @foreach (var item in (from w in Model group w by w.Title into n select n))
    {
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "BudgetHistories", new { Title = item.First().Title })"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> <span>@item.First().Title</span></a></li>
    }

</ul>
```

The reason I have it set up the way it is above is because there are many transactions with the same title and I am grouping those transactions by the title and just displaying all those transactions with that title.

Comment: Actually, before I only had two months in there, February and March. I just assumed that it would do it incorrectly but I just added a January in there and it is ordering it correctly. All I had to do was put a .Reverse() at the end it's working perfectly. Could someone explain why and if it would continue to do so if a whole calendar year was put in. Thanks!

Comment: Put in a whole calendar year and test it by yourself. We don't know the model definition and how you fill the data - and the **how** is the main point here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GroupBy](https://www.dotnetperls.com/groupby) and [Reverse](https://www.dotnetperls.com/reverse) does not sort your data it might be working because `Title` is sorted in your data but you can change its order and then try to `Group` and `Reverse` to check its still sorted
you can try this

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">

    @foreach (var item in (Model.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Title, "MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ).GroupBy(x=>x.Title)))
    {
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "BudgetHistories", new { Title = item.First().Title })"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> <span>@item.First().Title</span></a></li>
    } 

</ul>
```

in above code `DateTime.ParseExact` converts the `February 2017` to `DateTime` format,
 Here `MMMM yyyy` represents [DateTime Format](https://www.vsni.co.uk/software/genstat/htmlhelp/spread/DateFormats.htm) of your `Title` because you can sort datetime and [OrderBy](https://www.dotnetperls.com/orderby) is used to sort the data in `assending order`

Comment: You've changed a Group to a Sort, so you also need to remove the calls to `.First()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a propery that converts the `Title` to a `DateTime` and then sort by this value.

This method will be useful in the future, such as getting a budget for a quarter or a year.

```
public DateTime When 
{ 
  get 
  {
    // The next 2 variables should really be static to the class.
    var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
    var format = "MMMM yyyy";
    return DateTime.ParseExact(this.Title, format, culture);
  }
}


@foreach (var item in (Model.OrderBy(x => x.When)))
{
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "BudgetHistories", 
       new { Title = item.Title })">
       <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> 
       <span>@item.Title</span></a>
    </li>
}
```

Comment: I would keep the date in the model and not some string representation of it. Then all other future operations on the date/month/quarter/whatever will be much more easier. To me it is a design fail of the model

Comment: @SirRufo, I agree DateTime and Title should be in separate fields in the model.  But OP asked how to work with the current model.

Comment: And the answer should be: Your current model design is wrong (not only for the string representation of the date)

Comment: BTW You already suggest to change the current model - why no suggestion to do it right?

Comment: Because all apps that populate the model would need to be changed and also the database (backing store)

Comment: How do you know we are talking about the model class used by the database? If so, you have the possibility to implement a ViewModel for the View. Inside the view there should be no calculating/grouping code only presentation. Anything else has to be done inside the controller. Just my 5cents